# How to get the co-ordinates of the clicked point using 'ol/Draw' in OpenLayers 6?

Tags: node-js, angular, typescript, openlayers

I am trying to create a measure tool using OpenLayers 6. I did get examples to measure distance and area using the ol/Interaction/Draw and ol/geom library classes. I want also to measure the coordinates of the clicked point. But I am unable to use the draw class when using "type: 'Point'"

I have come across examples in which this is implemented using the 'singleclick' event trigger on the specified map. But I am looking forward to do the same task using the latter mentioned method.
How can I do this?

I have implemented measure distance and area using the below code

```
mapHandlers() {
    const that = this;
    let listener;
    this.draw.on('drawstart', (evt) => {
      // set sketch
      that.sketch = evt.feature;
      let tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
      listener = that.sketch.getGeometry().on('change', (evt) => {
        const geom = evt.target;
        let output;
        if (geom instanceof Polygon) {
          output = that.formatArea(geom);
          this.measureArea = (getArea(geom, {projection: 'EPSG:4326'}));
          tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
        } else if (geom instanceof LineString) {
          output = that.formatLength(geom);
          this.measureDistance = (getLength(geom, {projection: 'EPSG:4326'}));
          tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
        }
        that.measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
        that.measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
      });
    });

    this.draw.on('drawend', () => {
      that.measureTooltipElement.id = 'ol-tool';
      that.measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static';
      that.measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
      // unset sketch
      that.sketch = null;
      // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
      that.measureTooltipElement = null;
      that.createMeasureTooltip();
      unByKey(listener);
    });
  }
```

I am referring to, [measure example in openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no `.getGeometry().on('change', ...`  event for a Point because it only requires a single click to draw it.

But you can check for a point at the drawend event

```
this.draw.on('drawend', (evt) => {
  const geom = evt.feature.getGeometry();
  if (geom instanceof Point) {
    const output = 'A point has no length or area';
    const tooltipCoord = geom.getCoordinates();
    that.measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
    that.measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
  }
  that.measureTooltipElement.id = 'ol-tool';
  that.measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static';
  that.measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
  // unset sketch
  that.sketch = null;
  // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
  that.measureTooltipElement = null;
  that.createMeasureTooltip();
  unByKey(listener);
});
```